# Why does Importing Pennylane give out cannot import name "shape"

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-import, quantum-computing, tensorflow-quantum

I am trying to import Pennylane in jupyter notebook. I installed it using Ubuntu.

```
import pennylane as cents
```

However, it is spewing out this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'shape'
```

I found two reasons online. One is that python needs to be at version less than 3.7[https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane/issues/1922]. To solve this I used `pip install -U jupyter`. Another reason is that Pennylane might be at a version earlier enough that it had a bug[https://discuss.pennylane.ai/t/importerror-cannot-import-name-shape/1383]. I installed Pennylane to the latest version I could find, 0.25. I did `pip install pennylane==0.25` But it still does not work

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Your code to supposedly update Python ("To solve this I used pip install -U jupyter") doesn't do anything to Python, and so it won't fix it. Jupyter is used to run a lot of languages in addition to Python. Please when posting point to your research so that others following your footsteps don't have to repeat it, bearing in mind 'others' might be a future version of you. For example, I assume [this issue](https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane/issues/1922) is the one that said you get that error when using outdated Python?

Comment: When inside a notebook, you can check the version of Python it uses by typing `import sys; print (sys.version)` in a cell. Pennylane installs and imports just fine in Python 3.8 when using `%pip install pennylane` in a notebook from active Jupyter sessions [here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/master) (give it a few seconds to spin up a session and open). (It's 3.7 and above it will work in according to that issue.)

Comment: @Wayne thank you very much! I added the links to my question now.

Comment: More importantly, did you make progress seeing if it is your Python version still that is causing you issues?